# What title should the page with tabs have?

Tags: usability, navigation, design, consistency, title

There is the **Events** page, which has two tabs - **My events** and **Shared events**.
The **My events** tab is opened by default.

[image]

The question is, what title should be displayed on the page?

1. Page title should be the same as the opened tab (**My events** or **Shared events**):

   - Gives a clear understanding of which events are shown.
   - Not consistent with the sidebar menu and the breadcrumbs.
2. Page title should be as it is (**Events**):

   - Consistent with the sidebar menu and the breadcrumbs.
   - Not clear what kind of events are shown - **My events** or **Shared events**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of the page should be Events. The problem with your UI is that the page title is in the wrong place. The page title should be above the tabs not below them.

See the below example taken from [Google's Material Design](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage).

[image]

Comment: Looks like I need to get rid of breadcrumbs?

Comment: @RomanPavlyk you don't need to. You just need to style them so that they don't compete with the page title and the tab titles as the primary information on the screen. See the link for why they can be useful https://www.nngroup.com/articles/breadcrumb-navigation-useful/.

Comment: And don't forget that the page title should also be in sync with the menu trigger which launched the page.

Answer (score 1):

As a user, does a page title in that spot bring any value?  It's already labelled on the tab itself.  It makes sense to remove it altogether since it's already in your breadcrumb trail.

(If you're looking to label the browser page title, then you'd need to also consider SEO.)

Also note that helpful categorization is often [mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MECE_principle).  You have "My Events" and "Shared Events," but is it possible for your own event to be also shared?  Would it then be duplicated under both categories?  (It's ok to do, but just understand that this could be more than a user would want to see and might indicate some improper design).